# How do I combine these two powershell script lines?

Tags: powershell

I'm so new at powerscript I don't even know the right question to ask, so I can't even search for what I imagine is a common question.

I have:

```
$temp=$_|Select-String 'Game started at: (.*?)\n'
$timestamp=$temp.matches[0].groups[1].value
```

I tried:

```
$timestamp=$_|Select-String 'Game started at: (.*?)\n'.matches[0].groups[1].value
```

and

```
$timestamp=$_|Select-String 'Game started at: (.*?)\n'|echo $_.matches[0].groups[1].value
```

which didn't work.

How do I properly combine the two lines into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your piped object(`$_`) was originally, but try this:

```
$timestamp = $_| Select-String 'Game started at: (.*?)\n' | % { $_.Matches[0].groups[1].value }
```

`Select-String` pipes an array as results, so you need to use a foreach-loop(% is short alias) to loop through each string even if it's just one, and get the value you want.